# Is is any way to read all history from Google chrome history and save it in an excel sheet?

Tags: google-chrome

I search for a way that allow me read all history data from Google Chrome history and save it in any format for example excel sheet .. but i want a way in which i make it by copy data from page and paste in a sheet and formating it .. i search for automatic way or a tool ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google saves the history in an sqlite3 database located in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default (on Windows 7).

Try installing an [ODBC driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) for sqlite3, you will then be able to use Data->From Other sources (in Get External Data) -> From Microsoft Query to get hold of the file and the data it contains. (I haven't actually done this, I just opened the file in the sqlite manager addin in Firefox to have a quick peek.)

Comment: that's what i want i found it in C:\Documents and Settings\%user%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default in windows server 2003 and also found this free browser http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ that can open these db